# How do I set it so the text box is selected when prompt is called?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

```
public int dialog()
{
    Form prompt = new Form(); // creates form

    //dimensions
    prompt.Width = 300;
    prompt.Height = 125;

    prompt.Text = "Adding Rows"; // title

    Label amountLabel = new Label() { Left = 75, Top = 0, Text = "Enter a number" }; // label for prompt
    amountLabel.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F);
    TextBox value = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 25, Width = prompt.Width / 2 }; // text box for prompt
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = prompt.Width / 2 - 50, Width = 50, Top = 50 }; // ok button
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); }; // if clicked it will close

    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation; // enter

    // adding the controls
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(amountLabel);
    prompt.Controls.Add(value);
    prompt.ShowDialog();

    int num;
    Int32.TryParse(value.Text, out num);
    return num;
}
```

**This is what my prompt looks like when it's called**

[image: Prompt]

I just clicked a button to call that method. Now as you notice, the text box is not selected. How do I make it so that if this method is called, it will make the text box selected by default without having to click it or tab to it?

(I know this is minor but every detail would look nicer)

Comment: Lookup TabIndex property

Comment: Use `value.Focus()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx).

Comment: Just a side note, but you may want to name your methods in PascalCase: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order used to tab between controls is determined by the property [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This property is determined automatically by the order in which you add the controls (If you don't change it manually) The control with TabIndex = 0 will be focused at the opening of the form (Of course if the control could be focused)

Try with

```
prompt.Controls.Add(value);
prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
prompt.Controls.Add(amountLabel);
prompt.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean `Focused` ? Like this:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```

Write this code after your show dialog,It should work.

```
prompt.ShowDialog();
prompt.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First().Focus();
```

Or if it doesn't work try to set `ActiveControl` property before opening your prompt:

```
promt.ActiveControl = value;
prompt.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Only the 3rd block of code you gave works. Oh well, I prefer the other way since it saves code space. Since it works at least +1 :)

Comment: yes, Focus doesn't work because it's waiting for ShowDialog result,and doesn't go to the next line.anyway still you can use Focus method to give focus to your textbox programatically in other cases =).